# HQL Query exception while using SELECT clause in Oracle CCB Utilities framework

Tags: hibernate, oracle-ccb

I am getting an issue in hql (Oracle CC&B Utilities Framework)

My SQL query is

```
select msg.EXT_MSG_ID, msg.MKTMSG_ID
from  O2_IN_CA_MSG msg
where EXT_MSG_ID = (select to_char(max(to_number(msg1.EXT_MSG_ID)))
                          from O2_IN_CA_MSG msg1, F1_BUS_OBJ_STATUS bostatus 
                          where msg1.BUS_OBJ_CD = bostatus.BUS_OBJ_CD 
                                AND bostatus.BO_STATUS_COND_FLG <> 'F1FL' 
                                AND msg1.BO_STATUS_CD = bostatus.BO_STATUS_CD 
                                AND msg1.BUS_OBJ_CD = 'O2-OESPCusTarIn'
                                AND msg1.SRC_DOC_ID = '12345678' 
                                AND msg1.MKTMSG_ID <> '179977027857'
                                AND msg1.acct_id = '7565333022'
                  )
```

HQL Query1:

```
FROM InboundCustomerAdminMessage inboundCustomerAdminMessage
WHERE inboundCustomerAdminMessage.externalMessageId = 
    (TO_CHAR(MAX(TO_NUMBER(inboundCustomerAdminMessage1.externalMessageId))) 
    FROM InboundCustomerAdminMessage inboundCustomerAdminMessage1, BusinessObjectStatus businessObjectStatus 
    WHERE inboundCustomerAdminMessage1.businessObject.id = businessObjectStatus.id.businessObject.id 
    AND businessObjectStatus.condition <> :boStatusCond 
    AND inboundCustomerAdminMessage1.status = businessObjectStatus.id.status 
    AND businessObjectStatus.id.businessObject.id = :businessObjectId 
    AND inboundCustomerAdminMessage1.sourceDocumentId = :srcDocId 
    AND inboundCustomerAdminMessage1.id <> :mktMsgId )
```

The exception is: ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here

I tried second query by using SELECT 
HQL Query 2:

```
FROM InboundCustomerAdminMessage inboundCustomerAdminMessage
WHERE inboundCustomerAdminMessage.externalMessageId = 
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(MAX(TO_NUMBER(inboundCustomerAdminMessage1.externalMessageId))) 
    FROM InboundCustomerAdminMessage inboundCustomerAdminMessage1, BusinessObjectStatus businessObjectStatus 
    WHERE inboundCustomerAdminMessage1.businessObject.id = businessObjectStatus.id.businessObject.id 
    AND businessObjectStatus.condition <> :boStatusCond 
    AND inboundCustomerAdminMessage1.status = businessObjectStatus.id.status 
    AND businessObjectStatus.id.businessObject.id = :businessObjectId 
    AND inboundCustomerAdminMessage1.sourceDocumentId = :srcDocId 
    AND inboundCustomerAdminMessage1.id <> :mktMsgId )
```

This time exceptio is:
Error creating hibernate query `'FROM InboundCustomerAdminMessage inboundCustomerAdminMessage WHERE inboundCustomerAdminMessage.externalMessageId =  all (select TO_CHAR(MAX(TO_NUMBER(inboundCustomerAdminMessage1.externalMessageId)))  FROM InboundCustomerAdminMessage inboundCustomerAdminMessage1, BusinessObjectStatus businessObjectStatus  WHERE inboundCustomerAdminMessage1.businessObject.id = businessObjectStatus.id.businessObject.id  AND businessObjectStatus.condition <> :boStatusCond  AND inboundCustomerAdminMessage1.status = businessObjectStatus.id.status  AND businessObjectStatus.id.businessObject.id = :businessObjectId  AND inboundCustomerAdminMessage1.sourceDocumentId = :srcDocId  AND inboundCustomerAdminMessage1.id <> :mktMsgId ) '`

org.hibernate.QueryException: **( expected before ) in select** [select inboundCustomerAdminMessage.externalMessageId FROM com.splwg.domain.mtm.inbound.inboundCustomerAdminMessage.InboundCustomerAdminMessage__ inboundCustomerAdminMessage WHERE inboundCustomerAdminMessage.externalMessageId =  all (select TO_CHAR(MAX(TO_NUMBER(inboundCustomerAdminMessage1.externalMessageId)))  FROM com.splwg.domain.mtm.inbound.inboundCustomerAdminMessage.InboundCustomerAdminMessage__ inboundCustomerAdminMessage1, com.splwg.domain.common.businessObject.BusinessObjectStatus__ businessObjectStatus  WHERE inboundCustomerAdminMessage1.businessObject.id = businessObjectStatus.id.businessObject.id  AND businessObjectStatus.condition <> :boStatusCond  AND inboundCustomerAdminMessage1.status = businessObjectStatus.id.status  AND businessObjectStatus.id.businessObject.id = :businessObjectId  AND inboundCustomerAdminMessage1.sourceDocumentId = :srcDocId  AND inboundCustomerAdminMessage1.id <> :mktMsgId )  order by inboundCustomerAdminMessage.externalMessageId desc]

Can you please help anyone on how to use SELECT clause in hql.

Answer (score 1):

Remove "order by inboundCustomerAdminMessage.externalMessageId desc" in your HQL